# invalid syntax on mysql : nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, aws-lambda

Newbie to nodejs.
I am thrown an invalid syntax error.
This is probably coming up from trying to escape characters.

```
let i = 0;
while(i < answered.length){
    let td = [
        connection.escape(questionnaireId),
        connection.escape(sId),
        connection.escape(questionId),
        connection.escape(answered[i]),
        connection.escape(hutk)
    ];
    values.push(td);
    i++;
}

let sql = "INSERT INTO answers (qId, sId, key, value, hutk) VALUES ?";
connection.query(sql, [values], function(err, result){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("Successfull Insert");
    connection.release();
});
```

I get

> "errno": 1064,
>       "sqlMessage": "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'key, value, hutk) VALUES ('18',
>   '\'yZfXqYnvIXmLMuDAthbRr7IHtkFp5cl2ZSPCsEwY\'', ' at line 1",
>       "sqlState": "42000",
>       "index": 0,
>
> ```
> "sql": "INSERT INTO answers (qId, sId, key, value, hutk) VALUES ('18', '\\'yZfXqYnvIXmLMuDAthbRr7IHtkFp5cl2ZSPCsEwY\\'', '5','\\'23@sd.lk\\'', '\\'f98a7585ce8d984a902df90263cdab5d\\'')"
> ```

Comment: What about wrapping the escaped `sId` with a backtick (`)?

Comment: As in connection.escape('`' + sId + '`')? @Zolbayar

Comment: Backtick around `connection.escape(sId)`

Comment: @Zolbayar since I'm using placeholders, do I need to escape the string?

Comment: Well, it won't hurt to try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Key a reserved Word in mysql Please try

```
 let sql = "INSERT INTO answers (qId, sId, `key`, value, hutk) VALUES ?";
```

You could put around all Columns, but this works too